# Setting a cookie in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to set a cookie in an iPhone Application that persists, so that later when the user is in Mobile Safari, that cookie can be sent to a webserver?

Comment: Here is the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837702/nshttpcookiestorage-state-not-saved-on-app-exit-any-definitive-knowledge-docume/15633164#15633164

Answer (score 16, accepted):

** Update 2017 **
A lot of changes to security mechanisms and cross-app communication were introduced to iOS in the recent years since this was first answered.

The below code no longer works on current iOS releases since Safari no longer accepts `javascript:...` in URLs and frameworks like `NSURL` catch these and return `nil`.

The one alternative that still works is to either host a website and have Safari open it or integrate such a HTML page in your app and run a small http server to host it on demand.

**iOS up to 6.x **
Since Apple has forced the *sandboxing* on all app store applications
there's currently no easy way to realize your request.

You could however open a special http://-URL from your application containing javascript to place a cookie:

```
NSString jsURL = @"javascript:function someFunction(){ /* your javascript code here */ } someFunction();void(0)";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: jsURL]];
```

Using javascript in URLs has been used by different iPhone applications to cross communicate
with MobileSafari (for example [instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com)).

Another option would be to include a static HTML page in your app or on your server and instruct MobileSafari to open it.
The page in turn could set the permanent cookie.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried this out and it doesn't seem to work. [NSURL URLWithString:@"javascript:function someFunction(){ alert('test!'); } someFunction();void(0)"] returns nil.

Comment: Using the iOS Safari.app you can't (not without jailbreak and file:// support).

Comment: javascript:// scheme does not seem to work, a least for iOS5/6

Comment: I would like to note that this answer is two years old and may not work with current iOS releases. As a matter of fact a bookmark with 'javascript:function()' still works

Comment: @ikarius - there is no place in my answer where I mention a 'javascript://' scheme - it's 'javascript:function someFunction(){...}' -- this has to be used exactly like shown above

Comment: This not working. Safari don't have javascript scheme!

Comment: @Shirkrin Ok, then read the first comment. [NSURL URLWithString: jsURL] returns nil.  I assume its not correct url string. just "javascript:alert()" not working too.

Comment: @AndreyM. You're right, this seems to be part of the tighter security in iOS these days. Safari also no longer accepts URLs containing javascript:.. I updated the answer to include this fact.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is made easy by using the ASIHTTPRequest Library. It encapsulates the use of the global cookie store.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

You can make requests with this library which will accrue cookies, and then these cookies will affect other requests later.

I use this to great effect in accessing authenticated APIs within my iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `NSCookieStorage`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) suggests that it would be such a mechanism. But whether "all applications" really includes Mobile Safari or not, your experimentation will have to determine....

See also the general documentation for the [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834).

Comment: Based on my quick experiments, The cookies I was saving using NSCookieStorage were only readable by the app that created them.  I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or if that passage in the docs is misleading.

Comment: I admit I've never actually used it in my own apps, but I did see comments on the web that seemed to indicate that others had had success with it. Sorry to hear that it didn't work for you. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at iPhone development, but wouldn't opening a UIWebView allow your server to set a cookie on the browser so then when the user visits the site with Safari the cookie would be readable to your web server? Perhaps a hidden or small UIWebView? I can't tell what the use case is from your question.

Comment: UIWebViews are sandboxed and use a different cookie storage to Mobile Safari