# How does Safari manage its cookies?

Tags: iphone, session, browser, cookies, safari

I recently realised that Safari in iOS manages cookie separately for Safari.app and other apps that embed UIWebViews. I concluded so because I developed browser based app and saw the following behaviour:

- login to web service which then sets session id to cookie.
- when I go to safari app and access the web service, I was asked to log in again.

Is it true that Safari in iOS manages cookie separately for safari app and other browser based app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Every app is *sandboxed*, meaning is has no access to any other app (which Mobile Safari is).

Thus, cookies set in a browser-based app will not affect the Mobile Safari app.

See this question for a possible workaround (kinda): [Setting a cookie in an iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604884/setting-a-cookie-in-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to track your mobile app installations. I would recommend checking out [yoz.io](http://yoz.io) because they are free and do not require an sdk.

Enjoy ;)