# Open whatsapp contact in iOS 9 from a different app

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

I want to be able to open a certain contact in whatsapp from within a different app in objective c. I am able to open a contact using the ABID In iOS8, however in iOS9 using the ABID only opens whatsapp in recent chats and not the contact provided. How can I open a certain contact in iOS 9?

An example of the URL in iOS9 is:

whatsapp://send?abid=4D2E5CD6-B4B7-4C37-BC6E-EF54479B43AF&text=text

Comment: I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712796/ios-custom-url-schemes-vs-universal-links-and-android-counterpart), for me it helped, try it.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? If so please share.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to open a contact in iOS 9 using addressBook for iOS 8, even though its deprecated. It seems WhatsApp didn't update the app to use CNContact.