# Passing Cookies from iPhone App to Safari App

Tags: ios, session, safari, session-cookies

All,

I have requirement,

In my application i logged in with my credentials and we are maintaining session based on cookies, In one requirement i need to send the cookies to Safari browser and maintain the session, Can we handle it in iOS,

Comment: This guy has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604884/setting-a-cookie-in-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be fulfilled in following way.
You could however open a special http://-URL from your application containing javascript to place a cookie:

```
NSString jsURL = @"javascript:function someFunction(){ /* your javascript code here */ } someFunction();void(0)";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: jsURL]];
```

Similar Question is asked at answered at link [Setting a cookie in an iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604884/setting-a-cookie-in-an-iphone-app)